# Is there a published protocol standard for home environment and appliance control via the Internet?

Tags: iot, appliance

I am starting to look into home environment and appliance control via the Internet.

I have an infotainment background that includes audio transport in distributed infotainment systems via MOST and Ethernet.  For the latter I have experience with IEEE1722 (IEEE 1722 - LAYER 2 TRANSPORT PROTOCOL WORKING GROUP FOR TIME-SENSITVE STREAMS).

As I looked into IoT and the home domain (I use that term loosely to include appliances, security, environment, landscape maintenance) I had hoped to find a standard command and control protocol, for example something analogous to IEEE1722.1, but applicable to command and control in the home domain.

I did some searching and I see there are a number of packaged solutions (i.e. products and software recommendations) available.  There are also a number of kits out there (e.g. RPI3 and Beaglebone Black, TINI) that would be useful platforms for a type of home controller however I found no mention of a standard protocol for command and control of the home apps.  We have the lower layer protocols like IP, TCP, UDP, SSL, HTTP ... etc but as far as I could tell no standard application layer protocol.

Does such a protocol standard (either formal or de-facto) exist?  If so could you please provide a pointer to it?

BTW there was a hit on my search in Stackoverflow:
"Is there any standard for Smart Home?"  But from what I could tell that was someone asking for the answer to questions posed by their classroom lecturer.  It had -1 votes.  My questions is not that.

Thanks in advance.

Jim

Comment: How domain-specific do you want it to be? If you're looking for something application-layer for time sensitive device control, [OpenSoundControl](http://opensoundcontrol.org/introduction-osc) might fit the bill. If you want something silly, [RFC 2324](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2324.txt) turns 20 years old next month. :)

Comment: I was looking for more than a coffee pot.  Open sound control is domain specific for multimedia.

Comment: Did further searching and found:  http://www.knx.org/media/docs/Flyers/KNX-Basics/KNX-Basics_en.pdf and https://developer.apple.com/homekit/  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did further searching and found https://developer.apple.com/homekit/  and http://www.knx.org/media/docs/Flyers/KNX-Basics/KNX-Basics_en.pdf  and https://www.electronichouse.com/smart-home/home-automation-protocols-what-technology-is-right-for-you/#comments  Thanks